# Serialize and add multiple items to json

Tags: c#, json, methods

I need to add multiple items to a .txt file in json format. I have a method which add a ClienteModel object to the .txt, it works. This is my `ClienteModel` class:

```
public class ClienteModel
{
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Indirizzo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my **method**: (work in progress since i have to set a progressive id)

```
public bool CreateCliente(ClienteModel model)
{
    if (true)
    {
        model.IDCliente = StartID;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        ClienteModel deserializedCliente = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClienteModel>(json);
        File.AppendAllText(@"D:\AnagraficaClientiJsonMemory\clienti.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedCliente));
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente aggiunto correttamente.");
    }
```

The condition's true since will be: if my json is empty
There will be an *else* that will check if the json is populated and count the number of object to set the maxID.

I use `AppendAllText` to avoid objects overwrite, this is the output with the first deserialize event:

```
{"IDCliente":0,"Cognome":"a","Nome":"a","Indirizzo":"a"}
```

That's a valid json, but if i try to append another object:

```
{"IDCliente":0,"Cognome":"a","Nome":"a","Indirizzo":"a"}{"IDCliente":0,"Cognome":"b","Nome":"bb","Indirizzo":"b"}{"IDCliente":0,"Cognome":"cc","Nome":"cc","Indirizzo":"cc"}
```

And that's not a valid format.

I'm new to json, my project used lists, and i'm re-engineering it. What should i do?

Comment: You want a json array by the sounds of it `[{...},{...}]`. Just put your objects into an array and then call `SerializeObject` on that

Comment: Oh, nice to know, but i don't know i that will work. The method will be called by a click, that will get infos from textboxes, so i need to add every single item to the json file. As you suggest, i'll need to create an array for every ClienteModel model, that's not so object oriented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're adding another JSON element to a non-valid JSON array. Your file's content must follow the schema:

*[ { content }, { another content } ]*

Just like any [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_json_arrays.asp) out there will show.
What about serializing and deserializing the JSON from the TEXT dealing with a Json Array?

```
model.IDCliente = StartID;
var fileName = @"D:\AnagraficaClientiJsonMemory\clienti.txt";
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClienteModel>>(fileContent);
models.Add(model);
File.WriteAllText (fileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models));
MessageBox.Show("Cliente aggiunto correttamente.");
```

This way, you could do any other processing with the models. An alternative is reading the File's content looking for the closing character of the JSON (']') and append your new JSON before.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON supports arrays](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), ordered sequences of zero or more values.

You may represent your list of clients as a JSON array like so

```
[  
    {"IDCliente": 0, "Cognome": "a", "Nome": "a", "Indirizzo": "a"},
    {"IDCliente": 0, "Cognome": "b", "Nome": "bb", "Indirizzo": "b"},
    {"IDCliente": 0, "Cognome": "cc", "Nome": "cc", "Indirizzo": "cc"}
]
```

One important note is that you should *never* and I really mean **never**, combine serialization and deserialization with plain text operations like `AppendAllText`. That you thought this was viable probably lead to serious confusions. Once you do that, all bets are off when it comes to whether the resulting data is valid and if it can be deserialized.

What you've done is to bypass the serializer's API, creating your own, add hoc representation of aggregates and producing something that isn't valid JSON.

This goes for any data format, not just JSON.

Instead, leverage JSON's array support as exposed by your serializers API.

```
public async Task SaveClienteAsync(ClienteModel model)
{
    var path = @"D:\AnagraficaClientiJsonMemory\clienti.txt";
    var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);

    var deserializedClientes = json.Trim().Length == 0
        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ClienteModel>>(json)
        : Enumerable.Empty<ClienteModel>();

    var toSerialize = deserializedClientes.Append(model);
    var updatedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
    
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(path, updatedJson, Encoding.UTF8);

    MessageBox.Show("Cliente aggiunto correttamente.");
}
```

Note that by convention, you should strongly consider using a `.json` file extension to indicate that the file contains structured data formatted as JSON and not arbitrary text: `@"D:\AnagraficaClientiJsonMemory\clienti.json"`

Comment: System.IO.File does not contain a definition for WriteAllTextAsync/ReadAllTextAsync ?

Comment: @paranoidcoder It's in Netstanard 2.1. If you're targeting. NET 4.8, you may need to install a nuget package or use a different mechanism to read the file. I'll look into it when I have a moment and update the answer